# Type conversion from signed to unsigned problems

Tags: c++, templates, types

I have a function like the following:

```
template<typename T>
void myF(void* a, T* b, T c) 
{
    make_unsigned<T>::type newC;
    make_unsigned<T>::type* newB = ptr_cast<make_unsigned<T>::type*>(b);
    ...
}

template <typename T> T ptr_cast(void* ptr)
{
    return static_cast<T>(ptr);
}
```

Which is using the type_traits class. It works just fine in VS 2010, however it fails when I compile using an ARM compiler. The compiler is v. 5.02:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.ds5/index.html

I get: Cannot find file type_traits... I thought it was part of the standard library at this point?

I tried a custom implementation of make_unsigned instead:

```
namespace internal {

    #define MK_MAKEUNSIGNED(T,V)             \
    template<> struct make_unsigned<T> {     \
      public:                              \
        typedef V type;                    \
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct make_unsigned {
        typedef T type;
    };

    MK_MAKEUNSIGNED(sdata8, data8);
    MK_MAKEUNSIGNED(sdata16, data16);
    MK_MAKEUNSIGNED(sdata32, data32);
    MK_MAKEUNSIGNED(sdata64, data64);
    #undef MK_MAKEUNSIGNED

};
```

And modified to:

```
template<typename T>
void myF(void* a, T* b, T c) 
{
    internal::make_unsigned<T>::type newC;
    internal::make_unsigned<T>::type* newB = ptr_cast<internal::make_unsigned<T>::type*>(b);
    ...
}
```

Again, it works in VS 2010, but the ARM compiler gives the following errors:

```
internal::make_unsigned<T>::type newC; #276 name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name
^  
internal::make_unsigned<T>::type newC; #282 the global scope has no "type"
                            ^ 
internal::make_unsigned<T>::type newC; #65: expected a ';'
                                 ^
internal::make_unsigned<T>::type* newB = static_ptr<internal::make_unsigned<T>::type*>(b); #276 name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name
^
internal::make_unsigned<T>::type* newB = static_ptr<internal::make_unsigned<T>::type*>(b); #282 the global scope has no "type" 
                            ^
internal::make_unsigned<T>::type* newB = static_ptr<internal::make_unsigned<T>::type*>(b); #20 identifier 'newB' nis undefined
                                  ^
internal::make_unsigned<T>::type* newB = static_ptr<internal::make_unsigned<T>::type*>(b); #276 name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name
                                                    ^
internal::make_unsigned<T>::type* newB = static_ptr<internal::make_unsigned<T>::type*>(b); #276 name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name
                                         ^
internal::make_unsigned<T>::type* newB = static_ptr<internal::make_unsigned<T>::type*>(b); #29 expected an expression                                                          
                                                                                     ^
```

So I cant seem to get it to compile using type_traits or a custom implementation. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: `<type_traits>` has been standard for years, and yes, it has `std::make_unsigned`, which you can specialize.

Comment: Sure, if by "years" you mean 2; `type_traits` was part of TR1, but not in the language standard until 2011. [The ARM toolchain only accepts C++03.](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0529i/Cacgaafa.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a couple of `typename`s here and there...

```
typename internal::make_unsigned<T>::type newC;
// ^^^^^
```

Basically, `internal::make_unsigned<T>::type` is a dependent name, and it is assumed not to be a type unless you instruct the compiler with `typename`. VS is overly lenient and let's this go by.

Other than that, this won't compile:

```
typename make_unsigned<T>::type* newB = static_cast<make_unsigned<T>::type*>(b);
```

as you cannot `static_cast` from a pointer to signed to a pointer of unsigned.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And correction: I am not using static_cast directly. Rather I wrote a function that takes in a void* and static casts it to the template type. I did not show that correctly.

OP updated to reflect this.

Comment: @radensb: Technically that `ptr_cast` is still undefined behavior. You are not allowed to `static_cast` a `void*` to a type other than the original type from which the `void*` was obtained. For that you should use `reinterpret_cast` (which is still unspecified, but at least makes explicit what you are doing)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `typename`:

```
typename make_unsigned<T>::type obj;
```

Search for "dependent names" and "typename" on this site, you will get many topics discussing this.